# Terminal Colors

Tags: terminal

After enabling `CLICOLOR=1` in `.bashrc`, how do I specify colours for terminal operations. The only one I have seen is `LSCOLORS`=<*some string specifying the color scheme*> e.g. GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced. Which other terminal operations can I set color schemes for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

some commands support colors some don't, grep will highlight matches with the `--color` option, to configure see `GREP_COLORS`, i.e. use an ANSI color def. to indicate you want something other than red :-)

note the `--color` option must be set to something, see man grep

Comment: Hah, it appears we posted at the same time.  On darwin (at least) it's GREP_COLOR, minus the S.  I'm pretty sure it's the same on linux

Comment: yeah, it seems it's depricated but still supported, what we did not mention is the horrid trouble you can get into when you output ANSI sequences inside scripts and so on :)

Answer (score 1):

I've often seen grep output colorized:

`export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=always' GREP_COLOR=36`

Where color:

30..37 = black, red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan, white

40..47 = same as above, but background color